# How to change - INTERVAL 7 DAY?

Tags: php, mysql, intervals

I have this sql which I have always had to change the interval value by file edit

```
$sqlresult = mysql_query("UPDATE chassis SET oktodo = '1' 
             WHERE dtmcreated < '$date' - INTERVAL 7 DAY",$link) 
             or die(' Query failed: '.mysql_error().": ".$query);
```

I have added a piece of code that changes a value in the database config table
How can I alter `INTERVAL 7 DAY` to get the number from a database config table field

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable for the interval.  So, you can join in the `config` table:

```
UPDATE chassis c cross join
       config
     SET c.oktodo = '1' 
     WHERE c.dtmcreated < '$date' - INTERVAL config.NumDays DAY
```

It is still basically the same idea:

```
UPDATE chassis c cross join
     SET c.oktodo = '1' 
     WHERE config.vckey = 'set_date' and
           c.dtmcreated < '$date' - INTERVAL cast(config.vcvalue as int) DAY
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
I think I've led you down the wrong path as to my needs, the new entry I made to the database is
INSERT INTO `config` (`id`, `vckey`, `vcvalue`) VALUES (67, 'set_date', '33');
so basically it's in config/set_date .... so vckey is a  varchar(255) called set_date & vcvalue varchar(255) is where the changing number "33" is, if that makes sence, I'm terrible at explaining this kind of thing.

Comment: $sqlresult = mysql_query("UPDATE chassis c cross join
 SET c.oktodo = '1'
 WHERE config.vckey = 'set_date' and
 c.dtmcreated < '$date' - INTERVAL cast(config.vcvalue as int) DAY",$link) or die(' Query failed: '.mysql_error().": ".$query); gives an error of  Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near near 'SET c.oktodo = '1' WHERE config.vckey = 'set_date' and c.dtmcreated <' at line 2:

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this afterwards, Thank you for your help Gordon.

UPDATE chassis CROSS JOIN config SET chassis.oktodo = '1' WHERE config.vckey = 'set_date' AND chassis.dtmcreated < '$date' - INTERVAL CAST(config.vcvalue AS UNSIGNED) DAY